# Visual Studio 2013 Process Editor - Empty "Select Work Item Type" dialog

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to edit the work item types on our TFS server and the "Select Work Item Type" dialog I am seeing is empty. I've been using VS2013 to edit the work item template for Product Backlog Item. But this suddenly happened where the dialog is blank.

Has anyone seen this same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. It turns out, the cache gets corrupt and produces this issue (among other issues and strange behavior).

To clear your cache folder, go to

C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache

Source: http://henrywrites.wordpress.com/2012/11/19/tfs-vs2012-an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-been-added/

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can always use witadmin.exe tool to export / import work item type definitions (it's under \Common7\IDE\ folder)